# how can i rename a empty column in excel sheet using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to rename empty column with a column name  can you please help me

```
    CaseNumber  QueueName
0   3510926     AudioSW_India
1   3510937     ModemSW_LTEAS_RJIL_India
2   3510940     ModemSW_RILQMI_AndroidRIL_Taiwan_VT
3   3510944     ModemSW_Data_India_All_LTE
4   3510956     QIPL_IMS
5   3510980     MODEMSW_LC_INDIA_LTE_Protocol_VT
6   3511017     QIPL_IMS
```

I am using

```
df2=df.rename(columns = {" " : "Signal"}, inplace = True)
```

but i am getting error

> 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'to_excel'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First column is index, so possible `rename` is by:

```
df.index.name = 'val'
```

Or:

```
df = df.rename_axis('val')
```

But if want avoid write first column (`index`) to `excel`, use:

```
df.to_excel('file.xlsx', index=False)
```

EDIT:

There is problem if use `inplace=True` it return `None`, so `df2` is `None`, not `DataFrame`.